# How to use Retargetable Decompiler cURL API?

Tags: linux, windows, rest, curl

I'm on `Windows` and I'm trying to use the [cURL API](https://retdec.com/api/docs/decompiler.html) provided by `Retargetable Decompiler`. Since cURL is a Linux utility, I downloaded a `Windows` build from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html). Let's say I want to perform the following decompilation:
[image]
This is using the browser which works and produces a result. Now when trying to do the same using `cURL` from the command line, I get errors.

Output:

```
>curl --form "mode=raw" --form "input=code.bin" --form "architecture=powerpc" --form "endian=big" --form "raw_entry_point=0x0" --form "raw_section_vma=0x0" -u my-secret-api-key: "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations" { "id": "yVWe4pe5", "links": { "decompilation": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/yVWe4pe5", "status": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/yVWe4pe5/status", "outputs": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/yVWe4pe5/outputs" }}
{
    "code": 400,
    "description": "The input file is missing.",
    "message": "Missing Input File"
}
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: id
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: yVWe4pe5,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: links
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: decompilation
{
    "code": 405,
    "description": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.",
    "message": "Method Not Allowed"
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: status
{
    "code": 404,
    "description": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
    "message": "Not Found"
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: outputs
{
    "code": 405,
    "description": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.",
    "message": "Method Not Allowed"
}
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

Also yes, the code.bin is in the same directory as the command line (script). How can I make it work? <s>I actually prefer a solution in `Java` and not `cURL` but doing it in `cURL` first might be easier for understanding since no `Java` examples or documentation is provided.</s>

Comment: `input=@code.bin` ?

Comment: @JoeC: That didn't seem to matter. I added the `filename=code.bin` as well and that worked then. Plus, the part starting with the `{` was the output which I falsely used as input hence all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's pretty straightforward.

Starting the process:

```
>curl --form "mode=raw" --form "input=@code.bin;filename=code.bin" --form "architecture=powerpc" --form "endian=big" --form "raw_entry_point=0x0" --form "raw_section_vma=0x0" --form "target_language=c" -u my-secret-api-key: "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations"
```

Received (example) response:

```
{
    "id": "mKgBoLa3jo",
    "links": {
        "decompilation": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/mKgBoLa3jo",
        "outputs": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/mKgBoLa3jo/outputs",
        "status": "https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/mKgBoLa3jo/status"
    }
}
```

Getting the decompiled (example) code:

```
>curl -u my-secret-api-key: https://retdec.com/service/api/decompiler/decompilations/r8OW7AaAOb/outputs/hll
//
// This file was generated by the Retargetable Decompiler
// Website: https://retdec.com
// Copyright (c) 2017 Retargetable Decompiler <info@retdec.com>
//

#include <stdint.h>

// ------------------- Function Prototypes --------------------

int32_t entry_point(int32_t a1);
int32_t unknown_20ca300(int32_t a1, int32_t a2);
int32_t unknown_212363c(int32_t a1);
int32_t unknown_27a2ad4(int32_t a1, int32_t a2);

// ------------------------ Functions -------------------------

// Address range: 0x0 - 0x1ef
int32_t entry_point(int32_t a1) {
    int32_t result = a1; // r26
    if (unknown_27a2ad4(a1, 0x27a2ad4) != 0) {
        // 0x94
        result = -1;
        unknown_212363c(0);
        unknown_20ca300(0, 0x830000);
        // branch -> 0x54
    }
    // 0x54
    return result;
}

// --------------------- Meta-Information ---------------------

// Detected compiler/packer: gcc (gcc-powerpc-elf) (4.5.1 - 4.5.2)
// Detected functions: 1
// Decompiler release: v2.2.1 (2016-09-07)
// Decompilation date: 2017-10-06 22:50:25
```

And so on.