# "cURL -u" API Key Authorization with Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, http-post, authorization, apache-httpclient-4.x

I can use the `REST API` using `cURL` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613768/3764804) answer. Now I want to "translate" it to `Java` code using the [`Apache Commons HTTPComponents`](https://hc.apache.org/) library. I'm only having trouble adding the `API key` authorization header:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(DE_COMPILATION_URL);
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(API_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
request.setHeader("mode", "raw");
request.setHeader("input", "@" + machineCodeFile.toString() + ";filename=" + machineCodeFile.getName());
request.setHeader("architecture", "powerpc");
request.setHeader("endian", "big");
request.setHeader("raw_entry_point", "0x0");
request.setHeader("raw_section_vma", "0x0");
request.setHeader("target_language", "c");

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(responseBody);
```

This prints:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "description": "API key authorization failed (missing or invalid API key).",
    "message": "Unauthorized by API Key"
}
```

I tried different pieces of authorization code but none worked. What could be the problem? The API key is correct and works with `cURL`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I forgot a colon at the end. It's mandatory to include in the [`base64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(DE_COMPILATION_URL);
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64((API_KEY + ":").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
```